# Android Tcp Server/Client

Tags: android, tcp

I see a tutorial for server/client tcp comunication.The tutorial is :

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/

I put the server programm on android tablet and the client programm on another android tablet...I open port 6000 for the server.I put  server  ip adreess on client code...

the problem is the server and the client dont comunicate...
I follow the steps in a tutorial and i try the programms to emaulator but again dont comunicate..

Please help me

thanks 
panagiotis

Answer (score 0):

What did you use for SERVER_IP on the client ? You need to put the server IP address of your server here.

Comment: I put the ip adress to android tablet where is server program

Comment: Sounds good. You can check you can ping the two devices from your development machine, then you can check the ping from one device to the other (download an app for that). If ping works then the problem is in your app, else it's in the network (router, firewall, public/private IP, etc).

Comment: If i can ping from android tablet to another android tablet and works fine then the programm is false?

Comment: Ues, if you can ping it probably means you have a problem with the code. If you can't ping you have to solve the network issue first.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using local IPs, it's obvious it's not a router-firewall related problem as you are under the same net, so there would be only a few possibilities:

- There's nothing listening on that port on that IP on the server-side
- There's a local firewall on the server-side that is blocking that connection attempt
- You are not using WIFI so you're not under the same net.

If you're using public IPs, sum up the firewall blocking issue. There might be blocked ports blocking your connections.

You should make sure you can open that service some ther way, that would help you debugging where the culprit is. If you've already done this, I'd suggest using some debugging tool to trace TCP packets (I don't know either what kind of operating system you use on the destination machine; if it's some linux distribution, `tcpdump` might help).

All that assuming you have the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: 1)There's nothing listening on that port on that IP on the server-side---maybe
2)There's a local firewall on the server-side that is blocking that connection attempt---i dont think 
3)You are not using WIFI so you're not under the same net.---The tablets is the same wifi..

Comment: Then check the first of the reasons

Comment: The server and the client  installed to android tablets...The android version is 4.2.2.
i dont understand this :

"You should make sure you can open that service some ther way, that would help you debugging where the culprit is. If you've already done this, I'd suggest using some debugging tool to trace TCP packets (I don't know either what kind of operating system you use on the destination machine; if it's some linux distribution, tcpdump might help)."

Comment: How to understand if open a port  in my router??

Comment: It depends on your router and it's not the subject of this site, so I can just give you some orientation: You'll have to log in within the router and check `Forwarding` of ports. But if you don't want to do that, use local IP addresses, this way you can confirm or discard that problem as within the same net you don't have router-firewall issues.

Comment: how to use local ip adress??The tablets must have internet.If i use local ip adress then i dont have internet access?

Comment: i use local ip adress...The tablet ip adress is 192.168.0.100..This is a local ip adress..

Comment: the problem maybe is the port forward...but why?i follow instructions for opening ports in my router..??
i installed port scanner in server android tablet and say nothing port open...please help me